# install Brother MFC-J6510DW

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I have downloaded the drivers for this printer/scanner/fax and installed them but somehow the printer doesn't print, it responds to the computer when I give a print command but that's it.
Since yesterday I'm using Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (new Toshiba laptop deleted crappy windows 8)before this I had Ubuntu 12.04 and Lubuntu 12.04.
My other printer, a Brother HL-2130 laser, I have no problems whit. 
Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong or any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by "it responds to the computer when I give a print command"?

Comment: When I give the print command the display on the printer lights up and shows "receive" and then..... all quiet > nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Please visit; [Brother Drivers for Linux® distributions](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/index.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on) and read [Linux Informations](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on) for system requirements, installation procedures etc.

After you have done so proceed as followed:

1. Choose either:

> Printer (CUPS): [Driver Install](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1.html) or
>   Printer (LPR) : [Driver Install](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html)

2. Depending on your choice, proceed to follow the commands to install the required driver or (easy way) download the .deb file and install your drivers through USC (Ubuntu Software Center).

Comment: All ready did, I came that far. Drivers are installed. Print command > printer shows "receive" but nothing happens after that